# Set theory, is this a correct phrasing?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $A = \{k : k\in\Bbb Z^+, 1\le k\le p\}$. I want to create a set called $B$ that contains every even number of $A$.

For example if $p=7$, then $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and $B=\{2,4,6\}$.

Is $B = \{c \in A: c\,\text{is even}\}$ mathematically correct, does it contain every even number in $A$, or if not, how should I formulate it?

Comment: $B=\{k:k/2\in\Bbb Z^+,1<k\le p\}$ works without mentioning $A$.

Comment: $B=\{c\in A:\text{$c$ is even}\}$ is a mathematically correct way to write the set of even numbers in $A$.